# Unable to find a specification for `React-hermes` depended upon by `RNReanimated`

Tags: react-native

When installing pod getting React-hermes issue.
[!] Unable to find a specification for `React-hermes` depended upon by `RNReanimated`

You have either:

- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

How to fix that issue

Comment: You can paste ENV['USE_HERMES'] = '0' at the beginning of your Podfile. It works